# Get affected rows after Mongo update

Tags: java, mongodb

How can I instruct Mongo to return the affected rows after doing an update?
Currently it returns

```
{ "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 1 , "n" : 12 , "updatedExisting" : true}
```

which means 12 records was updated, but I want to find out which records they were.

One workaround is to do two queries, first to find the _id's, and second to actually update them but this is not good enough.

Many thanks

R.

Comment: I could use the same query for the find(). But that would be two queries to run. The thing is I can find and update in the same atomic query, it only doesn't return which rows where updated.

Comment: Use the [**`findAndModify()`**](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#findAndModify-com.mongodb.DBObject-com.mongodb.DBObject-com.mongodb.DBObject-boolean-com.mongodb.DBObject-boolean-boolean-) API.

Comment: A good example here: [MongoDB findAndModify() examples using Mongo Shell and Java Driver](http://www.journaldev.com/6221/mongodb-findandmodify-examples-using-mongo-shell-and-java-driver).

Comment: Thanks @chridam that's what I was looking for. If you make your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[`findAndModify()`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#findAndModify-com.mongodb.DBObject-com.mongodb.DBObject-com.mongodb.DBObject-boolean-com.mongodb.DBObject-boolean-boolean-)** API. For example, following the guideline from this blog post **[MongoDB findAndModify() examples using Mongo Shell and Java Driver](http://www.journaldev.com/6221/mongodb-findandmodify-examples-using-mongo-shell-and-java-driver)**, you can write your update query as:

```
    // findAndModify operation. Update colour to blue for cars having speed < 45
    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("speed",
            new BasicDBObject("$lt", 45));
    DBObject update = new BasicDBObject();
    update.put("$set", new BasicDBObject("color", "Blue"));
    DBCursor cursor = coll.find();
    try {
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
    coll.findAndModify(query, update);
```